# UIWebView opens safari on load

Tags: objective-c, url, uiwebview, safari, hyperlink

I have a UIWebView in my application. If I tell it to open the url @"http://twitter.com/"  it open in that same webView fine. But if I ask it to open a url like (similar to the one I need it to open): @"feed://www.OcataCore.com/rss/news.xml"  it opens up safari as soon as the view that contains the UIWebview is loaded.  Is there a way i can force that url to be opened in my webview ?

Comment: What happens when you use http:// instead of feed:// ?

Comment: @Pfitz : a blank white page is displayed when I use http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIWebView does not offer the same range of features as Safari does. Except html, UIWebView is capable to read the formats listed in [this Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008749). It appears like it is not capable of displaying XML, no matter if it is taken from a feed or a local file.

Answer (score 0):

agreed, should not be able to open XML files.

hope this helps though if you are just wondering how to open Safari. use this delegate method of UIWebView to open the links.

webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType

that should work.